# sklearn GridSearchCV with Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a pipeline which first does RandomizedPCA on my training data and then fits a ridge regression model.  Here is my code:

```
pca = RandomizedPCA(1000, whiten=True)
rgn = Ridge()

pca_ridge = Pipeline([('pca', pca),
                      ('ridge', rgn)])

parameters = {'ridge__alpha': 10 ** np.linspace(-5, -2, 3)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pca_ridge, parameters, cv=2, n_jobs=1, scoring='mean_squared_error')
grid_search.fit(train_x, train_y[:, 1:])
```

I know about the `RidgeCV` function but I want to try out Pipeline and GridSearch CV.

I want the grid search CV to report RMSE error, but this doesn't seem supported in sklearn so I'm making do with MSE.  However, the scores it resports are negative:

```
In [41]: grid_search.grid_scores_
Out[41]: 
[mean: -0.02665, std: 0.00007, params: {'ridge__alpha': 1.0000000000000001e-05},
 mean: -0.02658, std: 0.00009, params: {'ridge__alpha': 0.031622776601683791},
 mean: -0.02626, std: 0.00008, params: {'ridge__alpha': 100.0}]
```

Obviously this isn't possible for mean squared error - what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Those scores are negative MSE scores, i.e. negate them and you get the MSE. The thing is that `GridSearchCV`, by convention, always tries to *maximize* its score so loss functions like MSE have to be negated.

Comment: Can you point out any documents about this or it based on your test?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2439 
(I personally think it should be negative and not "negated")

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Do I have to use 'neg_mean_squared_error' in model.compile() for "loss" and metric" or 'mean_squared_error'?

Answer (score 7):

An alternate way to create `GridSearchCV` is to use `make_scorer` and turn `greater_is_better` flag to `False`

So, if `rgn` is your regression model, and `parameters` are your hyperparameter lists, you can use the `make_scorer` like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
#define your own mse and set greater_is_better=False
mse = make_scorer(mean_squared_error,greater_is_better=False)
```

Now, same as below, you can call the GridSearch and pass your defined mse

```
grid_obj = GridSearchCV(rgn, parameters, cv=5,scoring=mse,n_jobs = -1, verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get RMSE as a metric you can write your own callable/function which will take Y_pred and Y_org and calculate the RMSE.

[ref](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, I have stored results of negative MSE and negative MAE obtained from GridSearchCV in lists named as model_nmse and model_nmae respectively .

So i would simply multiply it with (-1) , to get desired MSE and MAE scores.

```
model_mse = list(np.multiply(model_nmse , -1))

model_mae = list(np.multiply(model_nmae , -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the scoring in the documentation

[image]

Comment: The question asks for why the RMSE values turn out negative; this doesn't seem like the answer to the question.

Comment: @Gust there is a 'neg_root_mean_squared_error', I thought it will be easy to get the RMSE right?

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks for your advice, here is the link to scikit learn document of scoring https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter