# How to compute SSE in python

Tags: python

I need to fit a linear model to Wine Quality dataset. And then find MSE for each k-fold. Following is my code

```
        regressor = LinearRegression()
        regressor.fit(Features_train, Quality_train)
        scores = cross_val_score(regressor, Features, Quality, cv=10,
             scoring='mean_squared_error') 
         print scores
```

Problem here is that one or two values of MSE are negative. Following is the scores array:

```
[-0.47093648 -0.40001874 -0.46928925 -0.4317235  -0.37665658 -0.52359841
 -0.40046081 -0.42944953 -0.36179521 -0.48792052]*
```

According to the formula, it shoud not be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do refer to this thread below:
[scikit-learn cross validation, negative values with mean squared error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error)

In summary, this is supposed to happen. The actual MSE is simply the positive version of the number you're getting.
Hope this helps!