# Negative result for regression using Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, regression

I was following the [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/) by Jason Brownlee, and finished section 2. Where his code apparently gave, as a result,

> Baseline: 31.64 (26.82) MSE

mine gave

> Results: -59.54 (45.45) MSE

I am intrigued by the negative result, since it's supposed to be the price of square meters (the case study is Boston housing data).

His code is as follows:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("housing.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:, 0:13]
Y = dataset[:, 13]


# define base model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal',
                    activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model


# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# evaluate model with standardized dataset
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100,
                           batch_size=5, verbose=0)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
print(results)
```

EDIT: 
result is now

> Using TensorFlow backend. 2017-11-17 15:19:20.550701: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use:
>   SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
>
> Results: -59.57 (45.48) MSE
>
> [ -21.09693904 -34.74104155  -24.24863872 -113.87524421  -80.55262979   > -98.56815988 -39.08693658 -150.61814082  -17.41903878  -15.52491613] Exception ignored in: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/zchihani/pythonEnvs/kerasEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 696, in **del** TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Interestingly (maybe), further calls did not show the 'exception ignored' part.

--end of edit--

I read [here](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/LcnsrWZ4mho) that "when the training error decreases to a certain level, the outputted prediction sometimes is negative".

The proposed response is to use

```
from keras.constraints import nonneg
```

but it does not say how or where...

For info, mu keras.json is

```
{                                                                                
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float64",
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

and the output of pip list (in the virtual env) gives

```
autopep8 (1.3.3)
bleach (1.5.0)
enum34 (1.1.6)
flake8 (3.5.0)
h5py (2.7.1)
html5lib (0.9999999)
importmagic (0.1.7)
jedi (0.11.0)
Keras (2.0.9)
Markdown (2.6.9)
mccabe (0.6.1)
numpy (1.13.3)
olefile (0.44)
pandas (0.21.0)
parso (0.1.0)
Pillow (4.3.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
protobuf (3.4.0)
pycodestyle (2.3.1)
pyflakes (1.6.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2017.3)
PyYAML (3.12)
rope (0.10.7)
scikit-learn (0.19.1)
scipy (1.0.0)
setuptools (36.7.0)
six (1.11.0)
tensorflow (1.4.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.4.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.4.0rc2)
Theano (1.0.0rc1+5.gab69bf0)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
wheel (0.30.0)
yapf (0.19.0)
```

Comment: just tested your code got this result: 'Results: 57.92 (42.26) MSE' I have no idea how you can get negative result, could you please add output from results variable?

Comment: @Paddy I suspected that much, it's the exact code I found in JB's tutorial... However, it's my first ever python and Keras code, could you tell me what variable should I print ? Thx

Comment: this one:

results

Comment: @Paddy, sorry :) I added the edit and amended the code.

Comment: @Paddy can you post what versions of Keras, scikit-learn, and tensorflow you're using?  I'm also getting negative MSE, and I've seen suggestions that Keras and/or sklearn are flipping the sign in some circumstances, on the assumption that greater values are better.  I'm using Keras (2.1.1), scikit-learn (0.18.2), and tensorflow (1.3.0).

Comment: sorry for the delay, I'm using Keras (2.0.8), Numpy (1.13.3), TensorFlow (1.3.0), and Sklearn (0.19.1)

Comment: @Stephen, did you solve the problem on your end? Do you have more info? I had no luck. I tried to purge the CSV data (kept only 50 lines, then 10 lines, then 1 line) and the result was still negative. I changed the orders in the keras.json, I tried many different leads, nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I need the space.

When I looked into this, I found that the now-depreciated `sklearn.cross_validation` is apparently supposed to return a negative MSE, based on the idea that greater numbers always indicate better results.  See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2439) for a discussion among the developers, especially [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2439#issuecomment-103909220) comment for a particularly unintuitive result.  It's also worth nothing that [sklearn.metrics.make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) takes a `greater_is_better` flag that lets the user customize this.

However, the non-depreciated [sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) is *not* negating MSE, including when I run it.  My guess was that the Keras wrapper was messing things up by negating the no-longer-negated MSE, but I can't find any documentation or anything in the Keras code to that effect, and somehow Paddy is running your code and getting the correct result.  I tried it again with scikit-learn (0.19.1) and tensorflow (1.4.0), and it's still negative.

So unfortunately my recommendation is to accept that the actual MSE is the negation of what you're getting, or to build your model without Keras and see if that works.  You could also try raising an issue with the Keras devs on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this results is not MSE, It's a "score".
**The loss is what one would like aim to minimise and  a score is what one would like to maximise.**
The difference is here:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/7788

And here is another similar problem:

[scikit-learn cross validation, negative values with mean squared error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error)