# How to get the train_error of RandomForestRegressior

Tags: python, random-forest, mse

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
grid = GridSearchCV(rf,param_grid=param_grid,cv=3,n_jobs=8)
grid.fit(train_X,train_y)
```

I use RandomForestRegressor like the codes above. And, I want to get the train_error. How can I do that?

to be more specific：（1）can I get  the "train_error" from the RandomForestRegressor ? (2) If I use "the mean_squared_error", how can I get the predicted value of the train data.

some pictures for my question.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(1)

You can use `.cv_results_` to get the mean squared error of each iterations. (Your cv=3 so there should be 3 of them).

```
cvres = grid.cv_results_
for mean_score in cvres['mean_test_score']:
    print(mean_score)
```

(2)

I think you couldn't get the predicted values with `GridSearchCV`. You might need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: The method(1) above returned results like this:  -0.143476163479
-0.114397135622
-0.0652798450285
-0.0444094919283
-0.0803082980101
-0.100409404264
-0.167920444638......    these maybe not train_error.

Comment: I use      grid.best_score_    to get a number 0.13028393891466461. Dose it means the mean_squared_error?

Comment: @user10025959, The actual those negative values are actually just the negative MSE. In GridSearchCV, to minimize MSE, the algorithm simply just maximizes the negative MSE. You could read more about it here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error)

Comment: Thank you for help. I think I have got it .