# GridsearchCV Negative Score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am using sklearn's [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to get best parameters for my [Random Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) Model.

Below is my code

```
model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 1, n_jobs = -1) 
param_grid = {"n_estimators": [5, 10]}



for parameter, param_range in dict.items(param_grid):   
    #get_optimum_range(parameter, param_range, RFReg, index)

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid = {parameter: param_range})
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    results = pd.DataFrame(grid_search.cv_results_)
```

My results dataframe is as below

[image]

If you observe my `mean_test_score` is negative but `mean_train_score` is positive.

What could be the reason for the same ?

My dataframe sizes

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

(538, 3)
(538,)
(112, 3)
(112,)
```

Answer (score 2):

In gridsearch CV if you don't specify any scorer the default scorer of the estimator (here RandomForestRegressor) is used: For Random Forest Regressor the default score is a R square score : it can also be called coefficient of determination.

> Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
>
> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual sum of squares > ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total sum of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0.

R square is basically the percentage of variance explained by your model.
You can also see it as how much better is your regression compared to a simple model predicting always the same value (the mean) (so a line in 2D).

If your R square is negative that means your model is worse than a simple horizontal line, that means your model doesn't fit well your data.
In your case your train R^2 is pretty good so that either means you manage to overfit your data (but it's unlikely) or simply that the test data is not similar to the train data.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that R^2 can be negative (detailed in other answers), it's worth noting that the scoring API is implemented to *always minimise* values, so in case higher is better for the user-supplied scoring function, the sign is flipped, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27323356/6917627.