# MLPRegressor gives very negative scores

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

I'm kind of new to machine learning and I am using MLPRegressor. I split my data with

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

then I make and fit the model, using 10-fold validation for test set.

```
nn = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100), activation='relu',
                     solver='lbfgs', max_iter=500)

nn.fit(X_train, y_train)

TrainScore = nn.score(X_train, y_train)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
        print("Cross-validation scores:\t{} ".format(cross_val_score(nn, X_test, y_test, cv=kfold)))
        av_corss_val_score = np.mean(cross_val_score(nn, X_test, y_test, cv=kfold))
        print("The average cross validation score is: {}".format(av_corss_val_score))
```

The problem is that the test scores I receive are very negative (-4256). What could be possible be wrong?

Comment: well i think this type of question asked previously check [this link that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error)

Answer (score 1):

To keep syntax the same, sklearn maximizes every metric, whether classification accuracy or regression MSE. Therefore, the objective function is defined in a way that a more positive number is good and more negative number is bad. Hence, a less negative MSE is preferred.

Moving on to why it may be so negative in your case, it could be broadly due to two things: overfitting or underfitting. [There are tonnes of resources out there to help you from this point forward.](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-overfitting-and-underfitting-in-machine-learning-a96b30864690)