# Why is the logloss negative?

Tags: scikit-learn, metric, loss

I just applied the log loss in sklearn for logistic regression: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html

My code looks something like this:

```
def perform_cv(clf, X, Y, scoring):
    kf = KFold(X.shape[0], n_folds=5, shuffle=True)
    kf_scores = []
    for train, _ in kf:
        X_sub = X[train,:]
        Y_sub = Y[train]
        #Apply 'log_loss' as a loss function
        scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_sub, Y_sub, cv=5, scoring='log_loss')
        kf_scores.append(scores.mean())
    return kf_scores
```

However, I'm wondering why the resulting logarithmic losses are negative. I'd expect them to be positive since in the documentation (see my link above) the log loss is multiplied by a -1 in order to turn it into a positive number.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is supposed to happen. It is not a 'bug' as others have suggested. The actual log loss is simply the positive version of the number you're getting.

SK-Learn's unified scoring API always maximizes the score, so scores which need to be minimized are negated in order for the unified scoring API to work correctly. The score that is returned is therefore negated when it is a score that should be minimized and left positive if it is a score that should be maximized.

This is also described in [sklearn GridSearchCV with Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050110/sklearn-gridsearchcv-with-pipeline) and in [scikit-learn cross validation, negative values with mean squared error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error/27323356#27323356)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it makes sense but still weird. I can not find any documents from Sklearn to confirm this.

Answer (score 5):

a similar discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error).

In this way, an higher score means better performance (less loss).

Comment: No this is not the case here. Please consider giving an answer instead of a guess. After some testing I rather blieve that it actually appears to be an error in the sklearn framework.

Answer (score -2):

I cross checked the sklearn implementation with several other methods. It seems to be an actual bug within the framework. Instead consider the following code for calculating the log loss:

```
import scipy as sp

def llfun(act, pred):
    epsilon = 1e-15
    pred = sp.maximum(epsilon, pred)
    pred = sp.minimum(1-epsilon, pred)
    ll = sum(act*sp.log(pred) + sp.subtract(1,act)*sp.log(sp.subtract(1,pred)))
    ll = ll * -1.0/len(act)
    return ll
```

Also take into account that the dimensions of `act` and `pred` have to Nx1 column vectors.