# Different values of the log-loss in statsmodels and sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, statsmodels, log-likelihood

The libraries [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) and [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) produce different values of the log-loss function. A toy example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['y','x1','x2'],
    data=[
        [1,3,5],
        [1,-2,7],
        [0,-1,-5],
        [0,2,3],
        [0,3,5],
    ])

logit = sm.Logit(df.y,df.drop(columns=['y']))

res = logit.fit()
```

The result of `res.llf` is -1.386294361119906, while the result of `-log_loss(df.y,res.fittedvalues)` is -6.907755278982137. Shouldn't they be equal (up to a small difference due to different numerical implementations)? The [statsmodels documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.llf.html) says that `.llf` is the log likelihood of the model and as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282884/why-is-the-logloss-negative/27364692#27364692) and [this Kaggle post](https://www.kaggle.com/code/dansbecker/what-is-log-loss) point out, [log_loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) is just the negative of the log likelihood.

Package versions: `scikit-learn==1.0.1`, `statsmodels==0.13.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, `res.fittedvalues` returns some negative values. If you want the prediction for your values, you should use `res.predict()` instead (values between 0 and 1).
You can calculate the log-loss in the following ways:
**1. Using sklearn log_loss:**

```py
log_loss(df.y, res.predict())
--> 0.27725887222398127
```

**2. Using statsmodels:**

```py
res.mle_retvals['fopt']
--> 0.27725887222398116
# or
res.llf / res.nobs
--> -0.27725887222398116
```

The very small difference is due to calculation rounding.

Note: In order to get the predicted values from `res.fittedvalues` you need to apply the expit function (inverse of logit):

```py
from scipy.special import expit

expit(res.fittedvalues)
```

This returns the same predictions as `res.predict()`.

Comment: great answer. Ignore `fittedvalues` in discrete models. Those are the linear predictors and not an expected conditional mean as in all other models :(

Comment: Yep, great answer! What does `res.llf` return though? Shouldn't this also agree with `log_loss(df.y, res.predict())`?

Comment: `llf` is the sum of loglike over observation, `res.mle_retvals['fopt']` is minus loglike / nobs. AFAICS, sklearn `log_loss` defaults to averaging not sum.

Comment: Thanks @Josef, I couldn't reconcile `llf`. I have updated the answer with that information.